# R Tidyverse expand a dataframe with all combinations of two variables (edgelist)

Tags: r, tidyverse

This code generates a data frame just so:

```
library(tidyverse)

A = c(7, 4, 3, 12, 6)
B = c(1, 10, 9, 8, 5)
C = c(5, 3, 1, 7, 6)

df <- data_frame(A, B, C) %>% gather(letter1, rank)
nested <- df %>% group_by(letter1) %>% nest(ranks = c(rank))
nested

A grouped_df: 3 × 2
letter1 ranks
<chr>   <list>
A   7, 4, 3, 12, 6
B   1, 10, 9, 8, 5
C   5, 3, 1, 7, 6
```

This is the desired data frame:

```
A tibble: 9 × 4
letter1 letter2 data1   data2
<chr>   <chr>   <list>  <list>
A   A   7, 4, 3, 12, 6  7, 4, 3, 12, 6
B   A   1, 10, 9, 8, 5  7, 4, 3, 12, 6
C   A   5, 3, 1, 7, 6   7, 4, 3, 12, 6
A   B   7, 4, 3, 12, 6  1, 10, 9, 8, 5
B   B   1, 10, 9, 8, 5  1, 10, 9, 8, 5
C   B   5, 3, 1, 7, 6   1, 10, 9, 8, 5
A   C   7, 4, 3, 12, 6  5, 3, 1, 7, 6
B   C   1, 10, 9, 8, 5  5, 3, 1, 7, 6
C   C   5, 3, 1, 7, 6   5, 3, 1, 7, 6
```

Once this step is solved, I'll run a mutate using `data1` and `data2` to get `value`, and then selecting `letter1`, `letter2` and `value` will give an edgelist. I'm working with about 700 letters and the ranks lists will all be the same size and contain about 20 elements.

I'd expected to be able to use expand or expand.grid, but to no avail.  Any tidyverse suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`crossing` can be used

```
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
crossing(ind1 = seq_len(nrow(nested)), 
  ind2 = seq_len(nrow(nested))) %>%
        pmap_dfr(~  bind_cols(nested[..1,], nested[..2,]) )
```

Comment: That takes me a long way there. I suppose I could then do a `crossing(node1 = nested$letter1, node2 = nested$letter1)`, then `cbind` the two.

Comment: @zazizoma sorry, i was thinking only the last column.  Updated

Comment: I'm going to need to meditate on the second solution. : ) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

We can use `crossing` after renaming the second dataframe.

```
tidyr::crossing(nested, setNames(nested, c('letter2', 'rank2')))


#  letter1          ranks letter2          rank2
#1       A 7, 4, 3, 12, 6       A 7, 4, 3, 12, 6
#2       A 7, 4, 3, 12, 6       B 1, 10, 9, 8, 5
#3       A 7, 4, 3, 12, 6       C  5, 3, 1, 7, 6
#4       B 1, 10, 9, 8, 5       A 7, 4, 3, 12, 6
#5       B 1, 10, 9, 8, 5       B 1, 10, 9, 8, 5
#6       B 1, 10, 9, 8, 5       C  5, 3, 1, 7, 6
#7       C  5, 3, 1, 7, 6       A 7, 4, 3, 12, 6
#8       C  5, 3, 1, 7, 6       B 1, 10, 9, 8, 5
#9       C  5, 3, 1, 7, 6       C  5, 3, 1, 7, 6
```

The same is also valid for `expand_grid`.

```
tidyr::expand_grid(nested, setNames(nested, c('letter2', 'rank2')))
```